# How to make chessboard.js work on a local WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, chessboard.js

I've a page "Chess" with a custom template. When I use the [cheessboard.js](http://chessboardjs.com/) script online there is no problem. When I want use a downloaded version of it and replace `<base href="http://chessboardjs.com/" />` with the local path, it produces this errors on the browser:

```
GET http://localhost/css/chessboard.css  (index):4
GET http://localhost/js/chess.js  (index):8
GET http://localhost/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js  (index):9
GET http://localhost/js/chessboard.js  (index):10
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

How to adjust the template `Chess.php`?

```
    ...
    <html>
<head>
    <base href="http://chessboardjs.com/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/chessboard.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="board" style="width: 400px"></div>
    <script src="/js/chess.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/chessboard.js"></script>
    <script>
        var init = function() {
            var board, game = new Chess();
            var makeRandomMove = function() {
                var possibleMoves = game.moves();
                if (game.game_over() === true || game.in_draw() === true || possibleMoves.length === 0) return;
                var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleMoves.length);
                game.move(possibleMoves[randomIndex]);
                board.position(game.fen());
                window.setTimeout(makeRandomMove, 500);
            };
            board = new ChessBoard('board', 'start');
            window.setTimeout(makeRandomMove, 500);
        };
        $(document).ready(init);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
    ...
```

Comment: Any errors in your browser JavaScript console?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is **NO** error description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<base>` attribute [*specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base). And you're probably placing the files inside your theme directory, and we get that with [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

The correct is to use [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wp_enqueue_scripts%20%5Btemplates%5D) to load JS and CSS files, and to do it only on the pages where they are needed. Also, don't enqueue external jQuery from external sources, use the one bundled with WP: `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`.

You could also [create a shortcode](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html) for this. The following is just a raw example with Chessboardjs files inside the directory `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/chessboardjs/`. And the template `page-chess.php` is this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Chess
 */
$base = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/chessboardjs';
?><html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $base; ?>/css/chessboard-0.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="<?php echo $base; ?>/js/chess.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo $base; ?>/js/chessboard-0.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="board" style="width: 400px"></div>
    <script>
        var init = function() {
            var board, game = new Chess();
            var makeRandomMove = function() {
                var possibleMoves = game.moves();
                if (game.game_over() === true || game.in_draw() === true || possibleMoves.length === 0) return;
                var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleMoves.length);
                game.move(possibleMoves[randomIndex]);
                board.position(game.fen());
                window.setTimeout(makeRandomMove, 500);
            };
            var cfg = {
              pieceTheme: '<?php echo $base; ?>/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png',
              position: 'start'
            };
            board = new ChessBoard('board', cfg);
            window.setTimeout(makeRandomMove, 500);
        };
        jQuery(document).ready(init);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```